# Ansible: Playbook to install packages using yum and dnf

Tags: ansible, rhel, rhel7, ansible-facts

I'm having problem executing an Ansible playbook to install a package using `yum` on RHEL7 and `dnf` on RHEL8.

I'm using a condition as shown on my playbook below, but keep getting errors.

**Error**

```json
{"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_os_family == \"RedHat\" and ansible_lsb.major_release|int == \"7\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ansible_os_family == \"RedHat\" and ansible_lsb.major_release|int == \"7\"): 'dict object' has no attribute 'major_release'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/ansible/master/intall.pkg.yml': line 9, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  # (Task-1) Checks if ansible_os_family == \"RHEL7\" and then Installs telnet on Remote Node\n  - name: Install telnet on RHEL7  Server\n    ^ here\n"}
```

**Playbook**

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: yes
  #become_user: ansible
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
  # (Task-1) Checks if ansible_os_family == "RHEL7" and then Installs telnet on Remote Node
  - name: Install telnet on RHEL7  Server
    yum: name=telnet  state=present
    when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat" and ansible_lsb.major_release|int == "7"

  # (Task-2) Checks if ansible_os_family == "RHEL8" and then Installs telnet on Remote Node
  - name: Install telnet on RHEL8 Server
    package: name=telnet state=present
    when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat" and ansible_lsb.major_release|int == "8"
```

How do I use my playbook to skip the RHEL7 and install the package on RHEL8 using `dnf`?

Thank you.

Comment: The first thing, of course, is `debug: var=ansible_lsb` and its friend `debug: var=hostvars` to see what ansible sees

Comment: can you confirm that `redhat-lsb-core` has been installed before executing the playbook? as `mdaniel` mentioned, you'll need to know the content of `ansible_lsb` , the error message is indicating that it doesn't have `major_release`

Comment: Not that even if it existed, `ansible_lsb.major_release|int == "7"` will never return true: you are comparing an int to a string

Comment: To avoid the chicken and egg problem (i.e. install `redhat-lsb-core` with a package manager I cannot choose until I installed `redhat-lsb-core`), have a look at the `ansible_distribution_*` variables which should be available out of the box. `ansible_distribution_major_version` should have the info you're looking for. But beside that, why don't you simply use the `package` module without checking for version? It should use the available package manager on the platform in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned within the comments by @Zeitounator you may have a look into [Conditionals based on `ansible_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts) since the fact respective variable is a string.

The following minimal example is working in an production environment.

```yaml
- name: "Install telnet on RHEL-{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }} Remote Node"
  yum:
    name: telnet
    state: present
  when: ansible_distribution == 'RedHat' and ansible_distribution_major_version == '7'

- name: "Install telnet on RHEL-{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }} Remote Node"
  yum:
    name: telnet
    state: present
  when: ansible_distribution == 'RedHat' and ansible_distribution_major_version == '8'
```

This is possible because of [Software management tools in RHEL 8](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/managing-software-packages_configuring-basic-system-settings)

> *Although **YUM v4** used in RHEL 8 is based on **DNF**, it is compatible with **YUM v3** used in RHEL 7. For software installation, the `yum` command and most of its options work the same way in RHEL 8 as they did in RHEL 7.*

This means that in your specific case by using the [`yum`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html) or [`package`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_module.html) module

> *This modules manages packages on a target without specifying a package manager module (like [ansible.builtin.yum](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-yum-module), [ansible.builtin.apt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-apt-module), …). It is convenient to use in an heterogeneous environment of machines without having to create a specific task for each package manager. `package` calls behind the module for the package manager used by the operating system discovered by the module [ansible.builtin.setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-setup-module).*

there would be no need for a conditional check unless there would be differences in the availability of packages and or naming.

A single task like

```yaml
- name: "Install telnet on RHEL-{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }} Remote Node"
  package: # or even yum
    name: telnet
    state: present
```

should just work.

Depending on your infrastructure and to be prepared for future releases you could switch to the [`dnf`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dnf_module.html) module for RHEL-8 and RHEL-9 instances.

```yaml
- name: "Install telnet on RHEL-{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }} Remote Node"
  dnf:
    name: telnet
    state: present
  when: ansible_distribution == 'RedHat' and ansible_distribution_major_version == '8'
```